# MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am getting getting following Error in LogCat When i register My BroadcastReceiver Programattically. I know i didnt unregister my BroadcastReceiver in Activity.

But i am not getting this error when i register through Manifest. Why??????

and also What does it mean MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver??? . will it create any problem in memory.

What will happen badly if I didnt unregister My BroadcastReceiver ???

```
    10-06 18:09:38.057: E/ActivityThread(15435): Activity com.collabera.labs.sai.MainActivity

 has leaked IntentReceiver com.collabera.labs.sai.MyBroadcastReceiver@41c8bc68 that was 

originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Comment: Do you stop your activity without unsubscribing the BroadcastReceiver? Check Android Activity Lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: yeah. I intentionally stopped my activity without unsubscribing the BroadcastReceiver. I want to know what things will happen badly if i didnt unregister other than getting the error in LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

A memory leak happens when an object is stored in the memory but can't be accessed, because the pointer to the object is deleted. It reduces the performance because it takes up memory and in worst case the system will crash.

Since Android is running i Java, the Garbage Collector should handle it but it is of course preferred to handle it correctly instead of leaving it to the GC.

Here is some information about memory leaks:

[Wikipedia - Memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

[Android - Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: " because the pointer to the object is deleted" . If there is no Pointer(reference) to a Object . It will be eligible for Garbage Collection. so we are safe right?

Comment: No. The IntentReceiver is registered somewhere, which will have a pointer to the object.

Comment: Yeah it is registered to the Mainactivity in this case, but when it's destroyed the pointer will be destroyed too.